# How to Add filter into a todolist application in Reactjs with using .filter

Tags: reactjs, filtering, material-ui

im new to react, trying to make an todolist website, i have the add and delete and displaying functionality done, just trying to add an search function, but i cant seem to get it working, where as it doesn't filter properly.

i basically want to be able to filter the values on the todos.title with the search value. such as if i enter an value of "ta" it should show the todo item of "take out the trash" or any item that matches with that string.

when i try to search, it gives random outputs of items from the filtered, i am wondering if my filtering is wrong or if i am not like displaying it correctly.

ive tried to pass the value into todo.js and display it there but didn't seem that was a viable way as it it should stay within App.js.

```
 class App extends Component {
 state = {
  todos: [
    {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      title: "take out the trash",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      title: "Dinner with wife",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      title: "Meeting with Boss",
      completed: false
    }
  ],
  filtered: []
};

// checking complete on  the state 

markComplete = id => {
  this.setState({
    todos: this.state.filtered.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
      }
      return todo;
    })
  });
};
//delete the item
delTodo = id => {
  this.setState({
    filtered: [...this.state.filtered.filter(filtered => filtered.id !== id)]
  });
};

//Add item to the list

addTodo = title => {
  const newTodo = { 
    id: uuid.v4(),
    title,
    comepleted: false
  };
  this.setState({ filtered: [...this.state.filtered, newTodo] });
};

// my attempt to do search filter on the value recieved from the search field (search):

search = (search) => {
  let currentTodos = [];
  let newList = [];
  if (search !== "") {
    currentTodos = this.state.todos;
    newList = currentTodos.filter( todo => {
      const lc = todo.title.toLowerCase();
      const filter = search.toLowerCase();
      return lc.includes(filter);
    });
  } else {
    newList = this.state.todos;
  }
  this.setState({
    filtered: newList
  });
  console.log(search);

};

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    filtered: this.state.todos
  });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    filtered: nextProps.todos
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <Header search={this.search} />
        <AddTodo addTodo={this.addTodo} />
        <Todos
          todos={this.state.filtered}
          markComplete={this.markComplete}
          delTodo={this.delTodo}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

search value comes from the header where the value is passed through as a props. i've checked that and it works fine.

Todos.js

```
class Todos extends Component {
state = {
    searchResults: null
}

render() {

    return (
        this.props.todos.map((todo) => {
        return <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo = {todo} 
            markComplete={this.props.markComplete}
            delTodo={this.props.delTodo}
            />
     })
    );

}
}
```

TodoItem.js is just the component that displays the item.

I not sure if this is enough to understand the issue 100%, i can add more if needed.

Thank you

Comment: One of the problem that I can see, is that you use the 'filter' javascript function. It's not what you're looking for. 
I'll suggest you something like that: 
```if (search) {
return this.state.todos.map(todo => todo.match(`/${search.toLowerCase}/g`))}
```

Comment: you have completely mixed up filtered and todos state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with your script. Looks to me it works fine when I am trying to reconstruct by using most of your logic. Please check working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q9jy17p47j

Just my guess, it could be there is something wrong with your `<TodoItem/>` component which makes it not rendered correctly. Maybe you could try to use a primitive element such as `<li>` instead custom element like `<TodoItem/>`. The problem could be your logic of `markComplete()` things ( if it is doing hiding element works ).

Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed it, thank for the help, it turns out to be my header, i wasn't passing in the props from the Header to App properly there searching was always wrong. Thanks for the help :P

Comment: Sure, no problem :)